# How to send data to perticular user using server sent events on django?

Tags: python, django, websocket, server-sent-events

I am new to **server sent event** please guide me. How can i send data from server to perticular client/user when change happen in database without reloading page. Also guid me if it is good to use **server sent event** or i should use **websocket** for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Server Sent Events is a good alternative for this problem.

> How can i send data from server to perticular client/user when change happen in database without reloading page.

The server need to keep an "handle" for all connected clients and it should use these connections to send data when a change in the database happens. This can be implemented in many ways, and you may start with how you can detect a "change" in the database.

Comment: Thanks for reply,    but i have 3 questions now    1) can i use signals here.     2)is it secure?    3) is it loads on server because i read somewhere that "streaminghttpresponse" is not good to use in realtime.